# Loading global monaco editor in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-extensions, monaco-editor

I'm writing my first vscode extension. I'm trying to load the underlying monaco editor that vscode runs. How do I access the global.monaco when inside my extension without using the vscode API?

Comment: I believe that's not possible. I tried myself to access it in some way, but apparently the Monaco editor is not exposed in any way.

Comment: Thats a real shame :/ so there is no way to unwrap the monaco editor from vscode API wrapper? My main reason is to try and porting firepad monaco adapter to use vscode. It supports monaco entirely but it needs the underlying monaco editor, as simple as getValue in monaco is getText() in vscode.

Comment: I'm looking into this myself, and I will follow up with what I find. My only clue is that vscode uses require.js and amd modules under the hood (thus why there are so many monaco examples with amd). I have had the lovely opportunity to work with the vscode team in the past on `monaco-graphql` before so I am confident I will find a good answer to this question. In fact, `monaco-graphql` is exactly what I'm trying to get working in an extension content provider, and I know you are an early adopter of ours, and may be part of the reason you're asking, so hi I would love to help!